# Test output of junit test was truncated

Tags: maven, unit-testing, junit

In quite a few cases, I noticed that the junit test output was truncated .
e.g. https://builds.apache.org/job/HBase-2.0-hadoop3-tests/org.apache.hbase$hbase-server/218/testReport/junit/org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure/TestDisableTableProcedure/org_apache_hadoop_hbase_master_procedure_TestDisableTableProcedure/ :

```
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.jav
...[truncated 1107895 chars]...
r$Handler.run(Server.java:2661)
```

If someone has seen this before, please advise whether there is any config which controls the truncation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you have looked what about this: https://builds.apache.org/job/HBase-2.0-hadoop3-tests/org.apache.hbase$hbase-server/218/testReport/junit/org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure/TestDisableTableProcedure/org_apache_hadoop_hbase_master_procedure_TestDisableTableProcedure/ if you take a look a line before there you can see: `...[truncated 1107895 chars]...`....this means about 1 MiB has been truncated ...which is done as far as I know by Jenkins...

Furthermore on the usual console log you can see things like this:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 763.13 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.TestDisableTableProcedure
[ERROR] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.TestDisableTableProcedure  Time elapsed: 749.128 s  <<< ERROR!
org.junit.runners.model.TestTimedOutException: test timed out after 780 seconds
```

If you have the need to investigate that more in depth you need to stop the build system and take a look into the workspace of the build and take a look on the surefire reports directory...

Apart from that it makes no sense to start such build by a timer trigger...better you commit trigger instead...